# My cron file are stopping after some time and restarting automatically

Tags: php, cron

I am running a php file via cron job every 5 hrs as it takes long time (Approx 4 hrs sometime). But I am noticing that some way its restarting again and again during this 5 hrs gap. (I can check it via my log file.)

Its getting some Connection time out on run manually via wget. May be this is the reason the cron stopping and running several time.

Can any one suggest me any idea to overcome this situation.

Comment: Depends on your code I guess. If you got a loop running until the connection could finally be successfully established, that could seemly be the issue. But that would not cause the complete script to be executed again and again but only some part of it running in loop